# mvc4 canot call a function in a controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

i have a view to display the information of a specific model.

in that information i have an image, which is a byte of array.

now i want to display that image.

i make this in my view

```
<img src="@Url.Action("getImg", "Image",  new { image = Model.image })" />
```

#### note that  the Image controller is not the same controller that the current view belong to

what am i getting wrong please?

all the other imformation  are displayed correctly.

#### Edit

this is the controller that i want to call

```
public class ImageController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /Image/

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }

    // To convert the Byte Array to the image
    public FileContentResult getImg(byte[] image)
    {
        if (image != null)
        {
            return new FileContentResult(image, "image/jpeg");
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a very poor choice in design. This code:

```
<img src="@Url.Action("getImg", "Image",  new { image = Model.image })" />
```

So the image will be sent as a byte array to the client (lets say 60,000 bytes).  Will create html that might look like:

```
<img src="/Image/getImg/?image=bc15b2c53... (lots of characters" />
```

This html is really long, basically sending the image as a byte array to the client.  Next the browser will make another request to get the image by sending the byte array back to the controller (another 60,000 bytes to the server).

Next, the controller will return the byte array sent to it back again to the browser, as an image.  Three trips of 60k of data is a terrible idea.

**Update**

The better way to do this is to not send the bytes array to the view, but an ID.

```
<img src="@Url.Action("getImg", "Image",  new { id = Model.id })" />
```

Then in the controller:

```
public class ImageController : Controller
{
  public FileContentResult getImg(int?/guid? id)
  {
    if (id.HasValue)
    {
      byte[] bytes = db.GetBytesById(id.Value);                                
      return new FileContentResult(bytes, "image/jpeg");
    }
    else
    {
      // be nice to the browser, send the correct result!
      return new FileNotFoundResult();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: i discovered that myself and i changed the parameter the id of the image but still the controller function for geting the image is not working

Comment: plase tell me why the function in the controller is not called?

Comment: I couldn't tell you exactly, but I would not recommend doing this AT ALL.  Extremely poor design.  Especially letting anyone send in any type of bytes that may actually not be an image.